# Who deleted my change in git?

Tags: git, revision

Here was my problem for the last 30 minutes: I had a couple of changes that disappeared in one of my files, and I don't know when that happened. And I want to know who did that!

I started looking for the revisions having my files:

```
git grep <searched_string> $(git rev-list --all) -- <file>
```

is the path to the file or a wildcard like *.gsp

I got a bunch of revisions, I look at the last one, and try to get it's children (thinking the first child should be the first revision where my changes disappeared)

```
git rev-list --children <revision_id>
```

is the 40 chars from the beginning of the last line of the previous command

Getting close! I am looking at the beginning of the output, and take the first child and then run

```
git log <revision_id_s_first_child> --stat
```

Then I look at the output and find my file and who did the change!
(it turned out, I was to blame...)

Is there anyway to do that faster (git blame would not show what has been deleted) ?

Comment: Did you try the "pickaxe", `git log -S`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "blame" a deleted line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-blame-a-deleted-line)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`git blame` has a `--reverse` option that takes a range of commits and shows you the last commit where a line existed before it was deleted.  So, you find a commit you know the lines were there, let's say `abcdef01` for example, and to show the last commit before the delete, do:

```
git blame --reverse abcdef01..HEAD -- <file>
```

Comment: It's a shame that `git gui blame` does not support `--reverse`!

Comment: What does this tell me here - 
`9597c8db (XYZ 2014-05-27 10:18:51 -0700  93)
8e4dbc16 (XYZ 2014-05-06 19:08:29 +0100  94)
1b4dbc16 (XYZ 2014-05-06 19:08:29 +0100  95)`

-700 and +100 what does it mean ?

Comment: Those are time zone offsets.  -0700 is probably the western U.S., 7 hours behind GMT. +0100 is probably Europe, 1 hour ahead of GMT.

Comment: Indeed `--reverse` shows "the last commit where a line existed before it was deleted". That commit might have nothing to do with the file under consideration though. It is the next commit that actually deleted the line: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870218/2097 to find this next commit. Does anyone know whether it is possible to have `git blame --reverse` show the relevant commit for each line, instead of the irrelevant commit it shows by default?

Answer (score 10):

If you know some substring that would be in the line that was removed, then you can use the `-G` option to `git log` to find commits that introduced a change that added or removed lines containing that substring.  e.g. if you knew that the word "pandemic" was in the line that disappeared, you can do:

```
git log -Gpandemic -p
```

(The parameter to `-G` can be a regular expression.)  This option was added rather recently to git - if it doesn't work, try `-S` instead, which has slightly different semantics, but should have a similar effect.

Comment: -G does not seem to work for me. -S would show me when it has been added, not when it has been removed

Comment: `-S` should show you when it has been added **or** removed (see the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)).  However, `-S` does this slightly strangely - it looks at the number of occurrences of the string in the the version before the commit and in the commit - so if you've just *moved* a line, for example, that won't be detected.  This is why `-G` is generally preferable, but that was only introduced in git version 1.7.4.

Comment: we got 1.7.3.4. Anyway thanks for the feedback, definitely interesting. Still can't see when my change has been deleted with -S, although the string I search is not present in the next revision at all.

Comment: You might need `-c` or `-cc` to show removals during merge (conflicts). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591569/923794)

Answer (score 3):

Note that since Git 2.11 (Q4 2016), you won't have to specify `..HEAD` if you want to look at commits between a specific one and the *current* one.

So [Karl Bielefeldt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389146/karl-bielefeldt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265218/6309) would then be:

```
 git blame --reverse abcdef01 -- <file>
```

See [commit d993ce1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d993ce1ed2f025708b0f78bed241466e35f1e8a0) (14 Jun 2016) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1172e16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1172e16af07d6e15bca6398f0ded18a0ae7b9249), 10 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### blame: dwim "`blame --reverse OLD`" as "`blame --reverse OLD..`"
>
> It is a common mistake to say "`git blame --reverse OLD path`", expecting that the command line is dwimmed as if asking how lines in path in an old revision OLD have survived up to the current commit.
>
> Instead of always requiring both ends of a range, we could DWIM "`OLD`", which could be a misspelt "`OLD..`", to be a range that ends at the current commit.

[`git blame --reverse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e1d09701a4fa3a4d15dd005e2b698934e4ae9ae0/Documentation/blame-options.txt#L31-L37) now include:

```
--reverse <rev>..<rev>:
```

> Walk history forward instead of backward.
> Instead of showing the revision in which a line appeared, this shows the last revision in which a line has existed.
> This requires a range of revision like `START..END` where the path to blame exists in `START`.
> **`git blame --reverse START` is taken as `git blame --reverse START..HEAD` for convenience**.

(Note of the note: ["dwim" is an acronym for "Do What I Mean" (not what I say)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dwim))

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya not sure yet: you can ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 1):

**git blame --reverse** can get you close to where the line is deleted. But it actually doesn't point to the revision where the line is *deleted*. It points to the **last revision** where the line was **present**. Then if the **following revision** is a *plain commit*, you are lucky and you got the deleting revision. OTOH, if the following revision is a *merge commit*, then things can get a little wild. As part of the effort to create **difflame** I tackled this very problem so if you already have python installed on your box and you are willing to give it a try, then don't wait any longer and let me know how it goes.

https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame