# How to figure out in which git commit a method go "lost"?

Tags: git, git-log

I had two git branches parallel to the master branch. Over time changes between branches had been merged back and forth which caused a way to complicated history, but that's nothing I can change now. What happened is, that some method M existed in branch B, which has been merged into master. "Most" of B is in master, but I'm missing method M. It probably got "lost" in a "wrong" merge. Trying to figure out, where it happened, I tried:

```
git log -S"def M"
```

and also

```
git log -G"def M"
```

I see the commit where the method has been introduced in the output, but not where it has been removed. Any hint what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591247/find-when-line-was-deleted

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you to find what you're looking for:
[git-bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)

This command is absolutely amazing when we need to find a specific commit. You simply defined the scope of the bisect and git automatically start the process by checking out a commit and wait on your feedback. At every step you check the desired method and git-bisect will get you at the exact commit where the problem started.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.