# How to find a commit that delete a keyword

Tags: git

Say I have a keyword `Tom` and I forgot that keyword in which file (because it already deleted) but I know in a certain branch. I want to find which commit delete this keyword.

Comment: Not exactly a dupe, but it answers your question perfectly: [How do I “git blame” a deleted line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-git-blame-a-deleted-line)

Answer (score 2):

Finding all commits which introduced to deleted a word is a [pickaxe search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309) (see diffcore)

```
git log -S"my expression" aBranch
```

To see the delta (and deletion)

```
git log -p -S"my expression" aBranch
```

The [alternative approach with git blame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463653/6309) would suppose you know where the expression was, which is not the case here.