# Find out which commit removed a particular word/line in GIT

Tags: git

With both GIT tools and command line, what is the easiest way to find out which commit removed a particular word from a file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the methods described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-blame-a-deleted-line):

> If you know the contents of the line, this is an ideal use case for:

```
git log -S<string> path/to/file
git log -G<regex> path/to/file
```

Or you could try:

```
git blame --reverse
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. But I actually forgot to mention a few details in this question. I created another post with more details for my questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203763/find-the-latest-commit-that-had-a-particular-word-line-in-git

Answer (score 1):

`git blame` will show you the most recent commit that changed each line of a file. You can use that on your file, and then go to the line where your word is.

Answer (score 0):

Type **`gitk`** in command line it would show the graphical tool for comparisons of the file.

(OR)

```
   $ git log -p
```

> One of the more helpful options is `-p`, which shows the diff introduced
>   in each commit.