# Find the latest commit that had a particular word/line in GIT

Tags: git

If I have a file with the latest commit like this:

```
class A {
    String name = "Mary";
}
```

In a particular commit,  `String name = "Mary";` was changed from  `String name = "Bob"`.  The thing is, this line has been modified a few times already (at one time it was `"John"`, another time was `"Adam"`)   so `git blame` is not useful. With Git, what is the easiest way to find out what was the last commit that had the line String name = "Bob" other than digging through the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my 
[go to command](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

```
git log -p -S <search term>
```

More info

```
-p 
Generate patch (see section on generating patches).
```

```
-S <string>
Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of <string>.
Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff 
output; see the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7) for more details.
```