# how to list commits that only deleted lines of code/text in git log <filename>?

Tags: git

If I only need to list the commits that performed deletions to lines of code/text in a file in  git is it possible to do so?

I know there is a way to list all files deleted in the a git repository using this command

> git log --diff-filter=D --summary

However what im looking for is slightly different. I only want the list of commits that did "deletions" on a particular file in git log. If that is even possible I don't know yet.
It would help me point out the commits that deleted lines of code cos "git blame" seems to not help me here and it is rather tedious to check commit by commit who was responsible to delete the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "blame" a deleted line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-blame-a-deleted-line)

Comment: I guess it is. Thanks!