# Find who deleted code in Git, when "log -S" shows nothing

Tags: git

I did commit `4cc698b`, and `git branch --contains` shows the correct branch with this commit.

After two weeks I saw what my code doesn't exist. But when I try to find who deleted my code, with `git log -S`, it shows only the `4cc698b` commit.

Does Git have another way?

Comment: You can go over the commits one at a time and see which was the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "blame" a deleted line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-blame-a-deleted-line)

Comment: As suggested in that question, try `git blame --reverse HEAD..4cc698b`. That will show you the last commit in which the line(s) in question existed. Then do normal `git log` (or `git log -p`) to find the next commit after that one; that should be the commit that deleted the lines.

Comment: `git blame --reverse HEAD..4cc698b` show my today `git pull` merge for all file lines

Comment: try: git log -p > somefile .  Then open somefile and search for the code that was deleted.   Then scroll up.  You should see the commit where it hapenned.