# How do I find removed lines with git?

Tags: git, version-control

From time to time it happens that I want to re-add some code which I removed from a repository some time ago. I always use tools like `tig` to browse the history to find the commit which removed some lines.

Is there a way to find removed lines with git? Something like `git-grep` but for commit *content* instead of commit messages?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-blame-a-deleted-line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you remember some keyword, *e.g.*, the name of a variable or function, in the removed lines, use [pickaxe search](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore#_diffcore_pickaxe_for_detecting_addition_deletion_of_specified_string) as in

```
git log -Skeyword
```

or to see the deltas along with the commit messages

```
git log -p -Skeyword
```

Although `-S` searches for exact string matches *a la* `fgrep`, you can search for regex matches with `-G` instead.

Note that the argument to `-S` or `-G` is “cuddled” with no space in between.

Documentation:

> **`-S<string>`**
>
> Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter’s use.
>
> It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a `struct`), and want to know the history of that block since it first came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the interesting block in the preimage back into `-S`, and keep going until you get the very first version of the block.
>
> **`-G<regex>`**
>
> Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match .
>
> To illustrate the difference between `-S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` and `-G<regex>`, consider a commit with the following diff in the same file:
>
> ```
> +    return !regexec(regexp, two->ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ...
> -    hit = !regexec(regexp, mf2.ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ```
>
> While `git log -G"regexec\(regexp"` will show this commit, `git log -S"regexec\(regexp" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the number of occurrences of that string did not change).
>
> See the pickaxe entry in [gitdiffcore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore#_diffcore_pickaxe_for_detecting_addition_deletion_of_specified_string) [reproduced below] for more information.
>
> ---
>
> #### diffcore-pickaxe: For Detecting Addition/Deletion of Specified String
>
> This transformation limits the set of filepairs to those that change specified strings between the preimage and the postimage in a certain way. `-S<block of text>` and `-G<regular expression>` options are used to specify different ways these strings are sought.
>
> `-S<block of text>` detects filepairs whose preimage and postimage have different number of occurrences of the specified *block of text*. By definition, it will not detect in-file moves. Also, when a changeset moves a file wholesale without affecting the interesting string, diffcore-rename kicks in as usual, and `-S` omits the filepair (since the number of occurrences of that string didn’t change in that rename-detected filepair). When used with `--pickaxe-regex`, treat the *block of text* as an extended POSIX regular expression to match, instead of a literal string.
>
> `-G<regular expression>` (mnemonic: `grep`) detects filepairs whose textual diff has an added or a deleted line that matches the given *regular expression*. This means that it will detect in-file (or what rename-detection considers the same file) moves, which is noise. The implementation runs diff twice and greps, and this can be quite expensive.
>
> When `-S` or `-G` is used without `--pickaxe-all`, only filepairs that match their respective criterion are kept in the output. When `--pickaxe-all` is used, if even one filepair matches their respective criterion in a changeset, the entire changeset is kept. This behavior is designed to make reviewing changes in the context of the whole changeset easier.

Comment: Just some additional info, if you want to search the case-insensitive string in one specific file: git log -i --oneline -G somestr* fileName