# Get first commit which did not contain a line in git

Tags: git, version-control

I'm interested in finding a commit in git that deleted a line by identifying *the earliest commit which did not include it*.

I'm aware of the `git blame --reverse` command but it shows the *last commit including* the line, which is not the same. I tried using that combined with `git log --reverse --ancestry-path <commit shown by blame>..HEAD` to find the commit I needed with some success, but it turned out tedious in certain cases.

Say I have the following graph

```
  /----G---H---I
 /      \   \   \
A----B---C---D---F--G
  \ /
   X
```

I know that A contains the line but G does not. The commit that actually deleted it was X. However, if I run `git blame --reverse A..G`, it will tell me that the last commit with that line was I. By doing `git log --reverse --ancestry-path I..G`, I will see that F was a merge so I will need to dig deeper by running `git blame --reverse A..D`, which will return H. Then I'll find G, only then finally A, which will allow me to find X.

It's not an unlikely scenario, I had this problem when we had a lot of pull requests merged into the main branch at a similar time, all branched off commits that still contained the deleted code.

Is there a command that would return the commit X straight away? Or at least is there a quicker way of finding it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "git blame" a deleted line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-git-blame-a-deleted-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log -S"this is part of the line that is added or removed"` will give you all commits that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file.

You can also make that string treated as a regex with `--pickaxe-regex`.