# How to find author name and commit id for deleted line of code in specific subroutine/under specific function in git?

Tags: git, python-2.7, github

How to find the exact commit id for deleted line of code under specific subroutine or function(As I have similar line of code in the same file under another functions). I have tried out with below command:
**git log -c -S"deleted line of code" -L "/^def functionName {/,/^}$/":file/path/filename.ext**  but somehow it is giving me results only for log range (-L) for subroutine. Though i can go through the results and able to find commit id in which the line of code was deleted manually, but i want to integrate the logic in a python script so need to find the exact data only through command. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4404444/2303202

Comment: when there are refactorings involved this is not trivial to automatize, some manual is still needed

Comment: @max630 Thanks for sharing a link as above.. i have already gone through that one before but seems not working for me as in my case same line of code is present in many subroutines so i have to limit the log output for same. Yes agree manually we can find it easily but i need to automate this scenario.