# How to find overlapping Git commits

Tags: git, git-commit, git-diff, git-blame

I'm doing a kind of archeology for my team's Git repo. The goal is to find all overlapping commits, e.g. all pairs of commits touching the same lines of code.

I tried to do this with diff and blame commands. The first one is not that reliable since code line ranges it provides have a sort of relative addressing. And it's hardly to track these addresses through 1000+ commits. The second option gives nice per file output but without any intermediate information (especially on deleting of a code lines).

I believe there must be a better way to achieve my goal. Looking forward for any advice!

Comment: Would git bisect help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404444/how-do-i-git-blame-a-deleted-line

Comment: Thanks for responses! I've read the post about blame already and bisect won't help me more then the rest commands. The problem is that I'm not looking for a commit with a particular properties, but I'm looking for a commits touching a particular commit.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used a tool written by [Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133374/albert), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66732834/15770). The source is in GitHub: [git-find-related-commits.py](https://github.com/albertz/helpers/blob/master/git-find-related-commits.py).

The tool compares the diff of each pair of commits in a branch to find most overlapping commits (as I understand it).