# How to find git commits which deleted lines in a file

Tags: git, csv, git-history

I have a large CSV file where data usally only get appended and then git committed.
But I am curious if there were some commits in the past which deleted lines from this file.
To date, several hundred commits have been made on this file.

**Is there an easy way to tell if there were git commits which deleted lines?**

Comment: What about [`git blame --reverse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11245051/10871900)?

Comment: If you just want to answer your question with "yes/no", then running `git log -p` and searching (`/`) for `^-[^-]` would be a quick and dirty way to find removed lines (the regexp means lines starting with `-` but not more than one, because that would match the `---` header for each diff).

Comment: Thanks @chelmertz this worked for me. If you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to answer your question with "yes/no", then running git log -p and searching (<kbd>/</kbd>) for `^-[^-]` would be a quick and dirty way to find removed lines (the regexp means lines starting with `-` but not more than one, because that would match the `---` header for each diff).